# JMeter : Individual Request data in Aggregate Report is not adding up correctly to Transaction Controller data

Tags: jmeter

I have excecated a test and got the following report and duration the analysis I noticed that the sum of the individual request data is not matching up to the transaction [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35oKu.png)

Help me around here to identify the cause of this issue

Note: For running one or few users I am not facing this issue, only during on higher user count this issue is coming up

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is an issue with the way you "excecate" the test (whatever it means)

Given the issue is not reproducible with "few" users and only happens under the load my expectation is that JMeter doesn't have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU/RAM/etc. or it's not properly configured for high loads.

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Make sure to set up monitoring of resources like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk IO, swap, etc. If you don't have other/better monitoring toolchain you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. If after following JMeter Best Practices the error is still there or resource consumption is way too high - consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
4. If even after switching to distributing testing the issue is still there check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

Comment: Now I even tried with 10User again in Ultimate Thread Group not able to get the correct values in the transaction controller. RAM,CPU usage are normal only                              
 Label           # Samples 90% Line
****************** 30 919
****************** 30 685
****************** 30 235
****************** 30 463
****************** 30 237
****************** 60 647
****************** 60 298
****************** 30 251
Transaction Controller 30 4730